# ¿Por qué mi aplicación Expo no envía los mensajes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, android-toast

Tengo una aplicación creada con Expo y el ala que tiene un formulario de contacto desde el cual enviar consultas.

Comencé con la aplicación ya construida, solo estoy configurando mis datos. El problema es que las consultas enviadas no llegan al correo que he establecido en la configuración, en un archivo (config.php) por lo que los mensajes deben llegar en modo smtp Esta es la configuración de mi servidor:

```
$emailConfig = array(
'address' => 'xxxxxxx',
'password' => 'xxxx',
'name' => 'jose',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.xxxx.es',
'smtp_port' => '587',
'smtp_encrypt' => 'tls'
);
```

La aplicación, la consola de depuración me muestra lo siguiente cuando hago clic en ENVIAR:

```
Toast is not defined
* application/components/PlaceFav.js:82:10 in render
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:11 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:14 in setImmediate$argument_0
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

El archivo al que hace referencia la salida de la consola es el siguiente, la línea:

```
renderItem = {({elemento, índice}) =>
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator, withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import{AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, View, Image, ScrollView, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import { Container, Body, Thumbnail, Text, List, Right, ListItem} from 'native-base';
import ConfigApp from '../utils/ConfigApp';
import FavListEmpty from './FavListEmpty';
import Strings from '../utils/Strings';

var styles = require('../../assets/files/Styles');
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class PlaceFav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      places: []
    }

  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchPlaces();
  }

  PlaceDetails (item) {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'PlaceDetailsScreen',
      params: {item}
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  renderFooterPlaces = () => {
  const places = this.state.places
  if (places.length != 0) return null;


  return (
    <FavListEmpty/>
   );
};

removePlace = async (place_id) => {
try {

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
uid = user.uid;

const places = await AsyncStorage.getItem('places');
let placesFav = JSON.parse(places);
placesItems = placesFav.filter(function(e){ return e.place_id !== place_id && e.userId == uid })

await AsyncStorage.setItem('places', JSON.stringify(placesItems));

this.setState({ 
...this.state, 
places: placesItems || [] 
}); 

} catch(error) {

}}; 

  render () {

    return (

<List>

<ListItem itemDivider>
              <Text>{Strings.ST1}</Text>
            </ListItem>    

<FlatList
          data={this.state.places}
          refreshing="true"
          renderItem={({item, index}) =>

<ListItem style={{paddingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor:'#FFF', opacity: 1, borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)', borderBottomWidth: 1}}  onPress={() => this.PlaceDetails(item)} >
              <Thumbnail rounded size={80} source={{ uri: ConfigApp.URL+'images/'+item.place_image }} style={{paddingLeft: 10, marginLeft: 10}} />
              <Body style={{paddingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0}}>
                <Text numberOfLines={2} style={{fontSize: 14, marginBottom: 3}}>
                {item.place_name}
                </Text>
              </Body>
              <Right>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removePlace.bind(this, item.place_id)} activeOpacity={1}>
                <Text note>
                <Icon name="close" style={{fontSize: 19}}/>
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

              </Right>
            </ListItem>

          
}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooterPlaces}


        /> 

</List>

    )
  }

    async fetchPlaces () {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      uid = user.uid;

      let placesJSON= await AsyncStorage.getItem('places');
      let placesFav = JSON.parse(placesJSON);
      placesItems = placesFav.filter(function(e){
            return e.userId == uid
        })
      const placesArray = placesItems || [];
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        places: placesArray
      });
  }

}

export default withNavigation(PlaceFav);
```

Todavía no tengo mucho conocimiento en React en Javascript y php, no sé qué significa este error y he buscado respuestas sin éxito. No se si lo que muestro es suficiente para que me ayudes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente descubrí el error, un error de principiante por el que lo explico si a otro usuario le pasa lo mismo que a mí.

El problema era que no estaba editando el código Backend. Quiero decir que estoy trabajando en el proyecto localmente y el Backend está en un servidor. Modifiqué el código en mis archivos locales, pero no subí las actualizaciones al servidor. Por eso no se enviaron los mensajes de la aplicación.

Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien más, y me hace pensar que debe verificar todos los posibles errores antes de buscar ayuda y solución. Gracias a este maravilloso sitio